# Adding colored bar to image with CSS

Tags: css, image, overlay

I have the css code below along with an image to show it's output.  I need help though 2 things.

1. This code works pretty good to show the username on the photo, however I noticed today while using chrome all day often when I would click a link that would take me to the page that has images with this code, it would not show the name on the image, it would just show the name below the image and the transparent black div would not be visible at all and the name would not even be on the image, I would then refresh the page and it would work fine, what could cause this, this was while my PC was acting like it was short on memory, could that be part of the issue?
2. I would like to make a bar show at
       the top of the image that is the
       width of the image and like maybe
       2-3 pixels tall and have a
       background color of like blue.  What
       I am wanting to accomplish is for
       femail users there will be a pink
       bar over there image and a different
       color for males.  Can someone who
       knows css help me modify this to do
       that the best please

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
div.imageSub { position: relative; }
div.imageSub img { z-index: 1; }
div.imageSub div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    line-height: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.imageSub div.blackbg {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #000;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
div.imageSub div.label {
    z-index: 3;
    color: white;
}
</style>

<div class="imageSub" style="width: 90px;"> <!-- Put Your Image Width -->
    <img src="http://cache2.mycrib.net/images/image_group66/0/43/t_6871399b0962b5fb4e29ce477541e165950078.jpg" alt="Something" width="90"/>
    <div class="blackbg"></div>
    <div class="label">Sara</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I've written this code for you, seems logical that I also try to fix it...

It seems that Chrome is struggling since it doesn't know the height of the element. Let's use margins instead of positioning

Also, since you are using a set height, you could drop positioning all together and use the following CSS (In which case you shouldn't need the above code):

```
div.imageSub img { z-index: 1; margin: 0; display: block; }
div.imageSub div {
    position: relative;
    margin: -15px 0 0;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    line-height: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.imageSub div.blackbg {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #000;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
div.imageSub div.label {
    z-index: 3;
    color: white;
}
```

**EDIT:** You've asked for a top colored bar for the gender. You can use the following HTML:

```
<div class="imageSub" style="width: 90px;"> <!-- Put Your Image Width -->
    <img class="female" src="http://cache2.mycrib.net/images/image_group66/0/43/t_6871399b0962b5fb4e29ce477541e165950078.jpg" alt="Something" width="90"/>
    <div class="blackbg"></div>
    <div class="label">Sara</div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
div.imageSub img.female { border-top: 10px solid red; }
div.imageSub img.male { border-top: 10px solid blue; }
```

Comment: Actually I might have to live with it as my images are different heights, it is hard to set a height for them.  Can you help me to add the top colored bar for gender please?

Comment: **@jasondavis:** I edited my post for the gender bar. As for the height, use my new CSS... I've removed my other solution.

Comment: My new solution (remove the use of positioning) will not trigger the problem in Chrome. And you won't have to specify the height.